# Application stops working when release apk is build using flutter but works in emulator when razorpay gateway opens

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, android-build, razorpay

I have completed the application with flutter and tried in the simulator where everything works fine. But when I build the apk file using **flutter build apk** command an app-release.apk builds up. When I installed the app-release.apk in the mobile the it runs but When I press the payment button ( which is using razorpay api) then the app suddenly stops working (but works fine in mobile simulator and also when actual mobile is kept as an emulator) the emulator mobile device is of Pixel 2 API 28. I have tried using

**I tried adding mavenCentral() to app level build.gradle and compile razorpay:checkout dependency**

Answer (score 1):

To use razorpay api you need internet connection. In emulator it comes by default so it works **but** for it to work on actual mobiles you need to add the following permissions in AndroidMainfest.xml. Procedure is as below..

**Step 1:** Go to android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

**Step 2:** Copy this line below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Step 3:** Put it in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.java2blog.helloworldapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

**Step 4:** Rebuild the the .apk and try on mobile it should work.

Comment: @JithinPal, If you like the answer please choose this answer as selected and vote.

Comment: @RajithaUdayanga: Can you please tell the package you are using for razorpay along with version. I will try and look for solution. And also check app-debug.apk on you mobile. if app-debug.apk is working let me know.

Comment: [Futter payhere](https://pub.dev/packages/payhere_mobilesdk_flutter) this. is the package that I am use and app-debug.apk is working and when I run the app in release mode in the android studio also fine. Only not working release apk.

Comment: @RajithaUdayanga: If app-debug.apk is working fine on your mobile device, then there is a separate procedure to create release apk, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH5Pawyw1n4 follow this video. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I found a solution. thank you for your help.

Comment: Stuck at the same point. Can you help @RajithaUdayanga